# Как создать корреляцию двух значений между собой?

Tags: java, int

Хочу создать подобие казино, и добиться соотношений, к примеру: при вероятности 50% выигрыш составляет 1.5х, а при 40% - 2.506х. 
Мне нужно понять сам механизм, как сделать так что бы `int a = 1;` при `b++;` стал бы `a == 3;`

Comment: создает класс, в нем int a,b, а также метод , который принимает значение для b, меняет его и автоматически рассчитывает значение для a.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно стоит создать хранилище, и в нем хранить множители в зависимости от вероятности ?

```
Map<String, Double> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("50%", 1.5);
data.put("40%", 2.506);

int number = 4;
double result = number * data.get("50%");

System.out.println(result); //6.0
```

Comment: Вообщем я решил не заморачиваться пока и просто 100 разделить на %, без странных соотношений